# Can't create Notes in Contacts exchange

Tags: python, exchangewebservices, contacts

I am trying to create a contact with Notes in it but instead contact gets created but I can't restore the Notes inside contact.

The dictionary key for is:"PersonalNotes".
While using the below soap message, I am getting API HttpError 500 error for user.
When I change the below soap message like("Hello"), my contact gets created but I can't see notes section in contact. I have also tried after changing the RequestServerVersion.
I have also tried after changing the  position in soap message.

```
<soap:Envelope
                    <t:Notes>
                        <t:Entry Key="Notes">**With Notes**</t:Entry>
                    </t:Notes>
                </t:Contact>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is soap message I am using to create the notes in contact.

```
response = self.client.post_retry(url='https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx', data=RestoreContact_SOAP, anchormailbox=True, content_type = 'xml')
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notes are just the body of the Item so to create them use the body property instead eg this should work

```
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateItem
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <SavedItemFolderId>
            <t:FolderId Id="AQMkADczNDE4YWEAMC03ZWZiLTQyM2QtODA1Yi02MmIyNmJkYWMyNmQALgAAA74c3T2WBidIkPPeS33fvkkBAHUQR/0Y6jBNnUCxQousINAAAAIBDgAAAA=="/>
        </SavedItemFolderId>
        <Items
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
            <t:Contact
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
                <FileAs>With Notes</FileAs>
                <DisplayName>With Notes</DisplayName>
                <GivenName>With Notes</GivenName>
                <Initials></Initials>
                <MiddleName></MiddleName>
                <Nickname></Nickname>
                <CompanyName></CompanyName>
                <t:PhysicalAddresses>
                    <t:Entry Key="Business">
                        <t:Street></t:Street>
                        <t:City></t:City>
                        <t:State></t:State>
                        <t:CountryOrRegion></t:CountryOrRegion>
                        <t:PostalCode></t:PostalCode>
                    </t:Entry>
                    <t:Entry Key="Home">
                        <t:Street></t:Street>
                        <t:City></t:City>
                        <t:State></t:State>
                        <t:CountryOrRegion></t:CountryOrRegion>
                        <t:PostalCode></t:PostalCode>
                    </t:Entry>
                </t:PhysicalAddresses>
                <AssistantName></AssistantName>
                <BusinessHomePage></BusinessHomePage>
                <Department></Department>
                <Generation></Generation>
                <JobTitle></JobTitle>
                <Manager></Manager>
                <OfficeLocation></OfficeLocation>
                <Profession></Profession>
                <Surname></Surname>
             <t:Body BodyType="Text">This is the Notes.</t:Body>
            </t:Contact>
        </Items>
    </CreateItem>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: ews restore api is throwing an 500 http error if I am trying to send unicode data in notes.
Any specific reason for that?